# Ahref html issue, html tags not showing

Tags: python

I don't seem to be having much luck solving this issue, i am pulling data from an xml url that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<task>
<tasks>
  <taskId>46</taskId>
  <taskUserId>4</taskUserId>
  <taskName>test</taskName>
  <taskMode>2</taskMode>
  <taskSite>thetest.org</taskSite>
  <taskUser>NULL</taskUser>
  <taskPass>NULL</taskPass>
  <taskEmail>NULL</taskEmail>
  <taskUrl>https://www.thetest.com/</taskUrl>
  <taskTitle>test</taskTitle>
  <taskBody>This is a <a href="https://www.thetest.com/">test</a> using html tags.</taskBody> 
<taskCredentials>...</taskProxy>
</tasks>
</task>
```

This part is where i'm having issues:

```
<taskBody>This is a <a href="https://www.thetest.com/">test</a> using html tags.</taskBody>
```

I pull the data using BeautifulSoup like:

```
# beautifulsoup setup
soup = BeautifulSoup(projects.text, 'xml')

xml_task_id = soup.find('taskId')
xml_task_user_id = soup.find('taskUserId')
xml_task_name = soup.find('taskName')
xml_mode = soup.find('taskMode')
xml_site_name = soup.find('taskSite')
xml_username = soup.find('taskUser')
xml_password = soup.find('taskPass')
xml_email = soup.find('taskEmail')
xml_url = soup.find('taskUrl')
xml_content_title = soup.find('taskTitle')
xml_content_body = soup.find('taskBody')
xml_credentials = soup.find('taskCredentials')
xml_proxy = soup.find('taskProxy')
print(xml_content_body.get_text())
```

When i print out this part, it prints like: **This is a [test](https://www.thetest.com/) using html tags.**

Instead of showing the ahref tag in full like: `This is a <a href="https://www.thetest.com/">test</a>`

I literally need the full string printed as is, but it keeps executing the html code instead of printing the string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't "execute" HTML code. I'm guessing you're viewing it in a web browser, and that's interpreting the <a> tags just like it's designed to.

Use [the `html.escape` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) to turn all tags into escape sequences (with `&gt;` and `&lt;` and the like), which stops the browser from interpreting them.

Comment: After some more debugging i tested:  `print("XML: " + str(xml_content_body.get_text()))` And also  `print("RAW: This is a <a href=\"https://www.thesite.com/\">test</a> string.")` the RAW part prints the html to the console as i wanted, the XML does not contain any html tags, i feel i am overlooking something here, i'll keep debugging.

Comment: @willerson `get_text()` specifically gets the text, not any of the markup. It strips out all the tags and only returns the text between them.

Comment: Holy cow that will explain it then lol from reading up i can't see the way to get the tags aswell as the text, or is this even possible with BeautifulSoup? thank you for the help at least i know i was doing some things right :)

Comment: @willerson Sure: `''.join(str(c) for c in my_element.children)` will return everything inside `my_element` as HTML with tags intact.

Comment: Thank you @Draconis appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

For Phython - Escape HTML Tags: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml
For PHP - Escape HTMl Tags: 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strip_tags2